# SAML SSO with Facebook Federated Authentication fails in WSO2 IS 5.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am following this blog post http://prasadtissera.blogspot.com/2014/04/login-with-facebook-for-wso2-identity.html to do SAML SSO with Facebook Federated Authentication. Everything works fine till Facebook redirects the request back to webapp back after authentication. In that point console gives following exception,

```
[2014-06-02 08:06:36,822] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.DefaultResponseBuilder} -  Error when reading claim values for generating SAML Response
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy.MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername(MultitenantUtils.java:50)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.DefaultResponseBuilder.buildSAMLAssertion(DefaultResponseBuilder.java:135)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.DefaultResponseBuilder.buildResponse(DefaultResponseBuilder.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor.process(SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.SAMLSSOService.authenticate(SAMLSSOService.java:140)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleAuthenticationReponseFromFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:546)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:163)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doGet(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:91)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[2014-06-02 08:06:36,823] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor} -  Error processing the authentication request
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error when reading claim values for generating SAML Response
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.DefaultResponseBuilder.buildSAMLAssertion(DefaultResponseBuilder.java:220)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.DefaultResponseBuilder.buildResponse(DefaultResponseBuilder.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor.process(SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.SAMLSSOService.authenticate(SAMLSSOService.java:140)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleAuthenticationReponseFromFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:546)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:163)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doGet(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:91)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy.MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername(MultitenantUtils.java:50)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.DefaultResponseBuilder.buildSAMLAssertion(DefaultResponseBuilder.java:135)
    ... 40 more
```

Can you please help me to solve this!

Answer (score 1):

Facebook authenticator in WSO2Identity Server 5.0.0 was designed to work with Graph API 1.0, but at the moment Facebook support for v2.0 that's why this problem may have occurred. So you can write a new Facebook authenticator and plug in to Identity server. please have a look to org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook to get implementation details.

Comment: Actually when I enabled the debug for this authenticator, what I can see is everything working fine. Claims retrieved well!Then where things can go wrong? Cant we correct that?

Comment: After some debugging I found that problems occurs in the 244 line of class. There we do, String authenticatedUser = (String) jsonObject.get(FacebookAuthenticatorConstants.USERNAME); Here USERNAME = username, but we don't have such a attribute in the json object map. By correcting that I think we can solve the problem.